# I made a hitbox sprite as a child to my player, in my player Class. how do I access that hitbox sprite in gamescene's didBegin method?

Tags: ios, swift3, sprite-kit

The purpose of this "hitbox" is so the player will only be able to jump while walking on top of ground/platforms.The hitbox is a little less wide then the player and is on the players feet. Here's my player class:

```
class Player: SKSpriteNode {

  let maxPlayerSpeed:CGFloat = 300
  static var isPlayerOnGround = false



    init() {

        //players texture
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "playerMove1")

        super.init(texture: texture, color: SKColor.clear, size: texture.size())

        //hitbox that sits underneath the player and follows him
        let jumpHitBox = SKSpriteNode(color: .red, size: CGSize(width: texture.size().width - (texture.size().width / 8), height: texture.size().height / 5))

        jumpHitBox.position.y = (-texture.size().height) + (texture.size().height / 2)
        jumpHitBox.alpha = 0.5
        jumpHitBox.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: jumpHitBox.size.width,
                                                                   height: jumpHitBox.size.height))

        jumpHitBox.zPosition = 3
        jumpHitBox.physicsBody?.pinned = true
        jumpHitBox.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        jumpHitBox.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypes.playerJump.rawValue
        jumpHitBox.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        jumpHitBox.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = CollisionTypes.ground.rawValue
        addChild(jumpHitBox)



        physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: size)
        physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypes.player.rawValue
        physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = CollisionTypes.star.rawValue | CollisionTypes.saw.rawValue | CollisionTypes.finish.rawValue
        physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = CollisionTypes.ground.rawValue
        physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        physicsBody?.restitution = 0.2
        physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        setScale(0.6)
        zPosition = 5
        physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.0 }

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder) //error here
        }
```

I want to use the jumpHitBox in this method as an additional contact.bodyA/B node in GameScene.swift:

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        if contact.bodyA.node == player {
           playerCollided(with: contact.bodyB.node!)


        } else if contact.bodyB.node == player {
           playerCollided(with: contact.bodyA.node!)

        }
    }
```

I don't know how to reference the the jumpHitBox child node from my player class in the didBegin in GameScene.swift.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I'm getting an error at the

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder) //error here
    }
```

I dont put anything in here in my player class but since moving the jumpHitBox sprite to a global declaration I get an error at the super.init(coder: aDecoder) line in the required init saying: Property 'self.jumpHitBox' not initialized at super.init call

Comment: hey GG, why don't you just use the `velocity.dy` like you did your jump under platform? Only this case, if dy == 0 (meaning not jumping / on the ground) then you allow the player to jump. That sounds *a lot* simpler to me than trying to keep track of platforms and hitboxes (which I used to do myself!!)

Comment: I was doing that actually, but if the player jumps next to a land chunk and is touching the land chunk in any way when he's at the peak of his jump, then he's able to jump again since at the peak of the jump theres a split second when your velocity becomes zero before you start to fall. My question is more for large chunks of floating land and not platforms though. I just used the term "platforms" to make my problem more clear. Thanks for the response!

Comment: hmm maybe if you just have it stall a frame to ensure that the dy is 0...

Comment: how would I do that? I've never heard of a "stall" frame? but that actually sounds like it would work.

Comment: will give an example later.

Comment: @Fluidity thank you!

Comment: I added a second answer. just try it out in a new macOS SpriteKit project, or change mouseDown to touchesBegan. The velocity idea didn't work because the gravity is constantly pushing the player down, even when on a platform. So I changed it to `position.y` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I would try the much simpler `velocity.dy` approach as mentioned in comments, your problem is that your hitbox is declared inside the scope of an initializer, so you can only access it there. If you give the hitbox a higher scope, such as a class property, then you can access it most anywhere:

```
class Player: SKSpriteNode {

  let maxPlayerSpeed:CGFloat = 300

  // This is probably going to cause you bugs later btw.. it should probably be
  // just a regular property:
  static var isPlayerOnGround = false

  // Now you can just call playerInstance.jumpHitBox :
  private(set) var jumpHitBox = SKSpriteNode()

  init() {

    //players texture
    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "playerMove1")

    super.init(texture: texture, color: SKColor.clear, size: texture.size())
    jumpHitBox = SKSpriteNode(color: .red, size: CGSize(width: texture.size().width - (texture.size().width / 8), height: texture.size().height / 5))
    //hitbox that sits underneath the player and follows him
  }
}
```

---

UPDATE:

```
class Player: SKSpriteNode {

  let maxPlayerSpeed:CGFloat = 300

  // This is probably going to cause you bugs later btw.. it should probably be
  // just a regular property:
  static var isPlayerOnGround = false

  // Now you can just call playerInstance.jumpHitBox :
  var jumpHitBox = SKSpriteNode()

  private func makeHitBox() -> SKSpriteNode {
    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "playerMove1")

    //hitbox that sits underneath the player and follows him
    let localJumpHitBox = SKSpriteNode(color: .red, size: CGSize(width: texture.size().width - (texture.size().width / 8), height: texture.size().height / 5))

    localJumpHitBox.position.y = (-texture.size().height) + (texture.size().height / 2)
    localJumpHitBox.alpha = 0.5
    localJumpHitBox.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: localJumpHitBox.size.width,
                                                                    height: localJumpHitBox.size.height))

    localJumpHitBox.zPosition = 3
    localJumpHitBox.physicsBody?.pinned = true
    localJumpHitBox.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    localJumpHitBox.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypes.playerJump.rawValue
    localJumpHitBox.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    localJumpHitBox.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = CollisionTypes.ground.rawValue

    return localJumpHitBox
  }

  init() {

    //players texture
    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "playerMove1")

    super.init(texture: texture, color: SKColor.clear, size: texture.size())

    physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: size)
    physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypes.player.rawValue
    physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = CollisionTypes.star.rawValue | CollisionTypes.saw.rawValue | CollisionTypes.finish.rawValue
    physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = CollisionTypes.ground.rawValue
    physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    physicsBody?.restitution = 0.2
    physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    setScale(0.6)
    zPosition = 5
    physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.0
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder) //error here
    jumpHitBox = makeHitBox()
    addChild(jumpHitBox)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, when would I use "let" vs "private(set) var"

Comment: I did what you suggested and I get this error: Property 'self.jumpHitBox' not initialized at super.init call. The line its referring to is actually in the "required init?" which has nothing inside it in my player class. I'm not really sure what it's telling me to do. I made a small edit in the OP explaining the issue, if you have the time please take a look. I would appreciate it.

Comment: @genericguy25 ok, you are using the SKS editor. let me see what I can whip up here.

Comment: @genericguy25 ok see if the code i added in the updated section works any better.

Comment: @genericguy25 also, `private(set) var` is because I didn't want to have to use a lazy property or use an optional (to keep the compiler from complaining). So i made it var (mutable locally) so I could assign it all the good stuff later, but to anything in your GameScene etc it will be considered a let (immutable). I made it just plain `var` now to keep it less confusing, and because I'm not sure if it was messing with the `required init(coder:)` or not.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try this out asap and will let you know how it goes. How do I call this in game scene.swift? "Player.jumpHitBox"? Also for my own sanity, why does using the .sks require these extra steps? I don't really understand the initial error i was getting.

Comment: @genericguy25 `playerInstance.jumpHitBox`.  I don't use the SKS editor but there are issues sometimes with the required init thing. I don't know if it is a bug in SK or just a poor design that requires extra leg work. Or maybe just doing it wrong...

Comment: Interesting, where does the "playerInstance" prefix come from? Is it like a special function or something? The Player class is capitalized and the actual "player" is initialized in gameScene pulling from the Player class.

Comment: @genericguy25 I was just being specific in that you need to use a player object instance to access the hitbox.

Comment: @genericguy25 I'm making this distinction because you have some object instances "WrittenLikeThis" and not "likeThis" which is going to be confusing ESPECIALLY when you are using static properties

Comment: Oh ok got it! I notice you say my static var isPLayerOnGround should be a normal property? I needed a way to get this variable to be used between classes, and this was the only way I found, is there a better way?

Comment: @genericguy25 generally you just pass around the player instance. Static properties are global properties. It's not necessarily "better" or "worse" unless you are trying to do something that requires a lot of forethought. Don't sweat it for now. Just focus on learning the API and you will pick up on what feels "right" for you as you go along

Comment: @genericguy25 one issue I can see though is if you use the crazy naming convention of `let Player = Player()` then you will have no way to distinguish between `Player.staticProperty` and `Player.instanceProperty`. Hence, why you should use `let player = Player()` and for literally all of your other classes / structs

Comment: You're right. In my gameScene.swift I have: "var player: Player = Player()" It works, but every time I see it in code I get a bad feeling because I forgot what its specifically doing besides letting me use the player class and the explanation behind it. What would you suggest changing it to for easy of use?

Comment: @genericguy25 that is right! `var player: Player = Player()` is right. Though you could shorthand it to just `var player = Player()`. But here, in your other question you did this: `private var JumpThroughPlatformObject = SKSpriteNode()` which is confusing... You literally had to call it "object" whereas if you just named it `private var jumpThroughPlatform = SKSpriteNode()` you would know automatically it is an object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149142/discussion-between-genericguy25-and-fluidity).

Comment: @genericguy25 im in tehh chatz

Answer (score 2):

One way to reference jumpHitBox from outside its class is by making it a property of the Player class as in `let jumpHitBox: SKSpriteNode`, in the same way as you have declared maxPlayerSpeed to be a property of the Player class.

If you make this change, then remember to remove the `let` in this line `let jumpHitBox = SKSpriteNode(color: .red ....` since you now just need to assign a value to it, instead of declaring it. You should also now move the call to `super.init` to be after this line. Otherwise the compiler will complain, i.e. all properties of a class must be assigned a value before calling `super.init`.

The jumpHitBox should be now be accessible in didBegin by using `player.hitBox`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! for some reason when I do either your suggestion or @Fluiditiy 's suggestion I get this error: Property 'self.jumpHitBox' not initialized at super.init call. The line its referring to is actually in the "required init?" which has nothing inside it in my player class. Please see the OP for a small edit explaining the problem better.

Comment: @genericguy25 Did you call super.init _after_ jumpHitBox  = SKSpriteNode(color: .red ... etc.)?  The error suggests that jumpHitBox is not assigned a value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a secondary answer showing a different approach to your problem. Note, the player only jumps when on the ground. This uses a "delayed frame" or "frame skip" or however you want to put it, because the jump command (pb.applyImpulse) is only called *inside* of `didSimulatePhysics` which means the character won't actually go any higher until the next frame.

```
// NOTE: This is a very simple example. The player bounces a bit on landing,
// which is essentially "landing lag" before you can jump again. In other words,
// the less the player bounces when contact the ground, the faster the player
// can jump again. There are ways to make this bouncing effect minimal / 0, but would
// require more work to implement, and I don't have any brilliantly simple ideas at the moment.
class GameScene : SKScene {

  var player = SKSpriteNode(color: .blue, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
  var initialY = CGFloat(0)

  var flag_wantsToJump = false

  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)

    let pb = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: player.size)
    pb.restitution = 0
    player.physicsBody = pb
    addChild(player)
  }

  override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    // Tells game that we want to jump next frame:
    flag_wantsToJump = true
  }

  override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Give us new, initial frame data to compare against whatever our position.y will be
    // later in the frame:
    let curY = player.position.y
    initialY = curY
  }

  override func didSimulatePhysics() {

    // Determine whether or not we want to jump next frame:
    guard flag_wantsToJump else { return }

    // Determine whether or not we are allowed to jump:
    let curY = player.position.y
    print(curY, initialY)

    if curY == initialY {
      // Even though we are calling .applyImpulse this frame, it won't be processed
      // until next frame--because we are calling this from inside `didSimulatePhysics`!
      player.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 75))
    }
  }

  override func didFinishUpdate() {
    // Clear our flags for new mouse / touch input for next frame:
    flag_wantsToJump = false
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I was doing some research on impulse vs skaction for things like moving character and jumping. Some say don't use physics based movement for 2d games, others say its no big deal. I move my player with impulses. do you think I should switch to SKActions?

Comment: @genericguy25 skactions make no difference. The thing that people are talking about is using _physics_ in 2d platformers, versus adjusting the _position_ of the sprites. Example, anything that causes your player to move via physics involves a physics body (impulse, force, velocity, etc). Things that don't use physics are `.position` or using `SKAction.move`

Comment: physics ARE difficult to use for platformers, as you are seeing, but the alternative is making your own hit-detection system, gravity, and jump commands. You *can* mix straight positonal movements with the physics hit detection, but that almost always causes issues / bugs that are nightmarish to solve

Comment: That makes sense to me. Thanks for the clarification.